# Comparing two dates in .Net using Access mdb strange error

Tags: .net, ms-access

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE [DateSync] > #2010-11-10 03:11:00#
```

This works if you run the query from in MS Access but if you get .net to submit it like this...

```
    Dim adapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter
    adapter1.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, conn)
    Dim table1 As New DataTable
    connection1.Open()
    Try
        adapter1.Fill(table1)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'will error here
    Finally
        'conn.Close()
    End Try
```

it throws an error....

> "No value given for one or more
>   required parameters."
>   Source="Microsoft JET Database Engine"

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that your SQL is exactly the same as what you tried in Access? One suggestion, qualify the fieldname in the WHERE clause, i.e., `WHERE Orders.DateSync...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: open connection and close connection are irrelevant here because the data adapter manages the connection automatically